# Xor of string in ruby

Tags: ruby, xor

I have a string, lets say "123|ABC|test|12345|FF" and I want to xor the ascii value of each character and print the result in hex.

What is the simplest way?

Answer (score 4):

Found it...

```
lrc = 0
input.each_byte do | c |
    lrc ^= c
end
hexVal = lrc.to_s(16)
```

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby 1.8.7 or 1.9.1:

```
input.bytes.inject { |a,b| a ^ b }.to_s(16)
```