# symetric encryption with key for javascript and ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, algorithm, security, encryption

I want to encode a number which would be maximal 10 digits long using a key with ASCII chars.

The encoded string should be decodable with the same key , which should return the decoded number.

```
10 => encoding_with("secret_pass") => hash => decoding_with("secret_pass") => 10
```

Both operations should work the same way in Javascript and Ruby.

What algorythm should I use for this purpose ?

All data should be in ASCII, no multibyte data for input, hash, and the key.

Comment: Just FYI, JavaScript cryptography inside the browser is a waste of time. See e.g. this for extended discussion: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Comment: doesn't matter, the question was not if it makes sense

Comment: Note also that you're looking for `ciphertext`, not `hash` - hash is, by definition, irreversible.

Comment: ROT13 then. Since this is client-side, no-assurances, in-browser environment, anything else is equivalent in terms of security.

Comment: @Pikvor: ROT13 doesn't use a key of ascii characters as suggested in the question... And if the key is not hard coded into the page then will looking at the sourcecode actually make whatever you do with it less secure?

Comment: @Chris: Good catch, should have said "XOR" - ROT13 is not applicable. If the key is not hard-coded into the page, then how does the page get it? AJAX? Oh look, *there* goes the key again.

Comment: You could put the key into one textbox and your plaintext into another and a third textbox shows you the ciphertext. You are right that if any of this goes over the network it could be insecure but the poster hasn't given enough context to be telling us if this is relevant. Oh, and you sound *really* patronising when you use phrases like "pray tell".

Comment: @Chris: I apologize for the sarcastic tone, that was indeed uncalled-for; edited that out. The point stands - using JS to simulate HTTPS is like using a hammer to cut the cake (for example, how do you ensure that the JS crypto code is legit?).

Comment: @Piskvor: Thank you. Much obliged. :) I will now agree with you that in general cases that you probably don't want to be doing this. I think somebody somewhere said something along the lines of "If you find yourself writing encryption code then your doomed to failure". I think I am going to stop thinkign about this now. Every time I come up with a new argument I realise (sometimes after commenting) that in fact you are still right. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple XOR should be sufficient.

[JavaScript](http://th.atguy.com/mycode/xor_js_encryption/)

[Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348991/xor-of-string-in-ruby)

Yes, you can go overboard and break out the full crypto suite, but since one part of the algorithm will run in-browser, in JS (completely untrusted environment), any attempt at Serious Cryptography™ will give you a [false sense](http://rdist.root.org/2010/11/29/final-post-on-javascript-crypto/) of [security](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/) (in other words, will actually make your system *less* secure).

If you're trying to protect the data in transit, use the tool that's made for the job; in this case, HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into some for of a [Symmetric Key Encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm), and the most prominent one [AES.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) AES is pretty much the standard and is implemented in both languages. Just make sure to use the same key and salt for encryption and decryption.

[Javascript AES](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html)

[Ruby AES](http://jdwyah.blogspot.com/2009/12/decrypting-ruby-aes-encryption.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be simple, and security isn't a great concern (since the javascript... observation in the comments), the easiest way would be to simple generate any random value, bigger (more digits) than the number, and simple XOR it with the number. This assumes the key (=random number) would be previously shared with the other program.

```
1. generate random number with 10 hex digits -> KEY
2. take the number then do (number XOR key ) -> result
3. send result
4. get the result and do (result XOR key) -> number
```

something better (stronger) would be to use any public-private key system. Exchange keys, crypt with public on one side, decrypt with private on the other side.

Comment: Are you suggesting to *hand over the **private key** to every user of the webpage*? Note that one side of the computation happens in JavaScript. That key would not be very *private*, IMNSHO.

Comment: @Piskvor: No, I would imagine that he was suggesting the public key was handed over. Though this obviously doesn't help since sending cyphertext alongside the key to decrypt it wouldn't make sense. I think though that you could use javascript to encrypt text on the client with the public key and send it back. Then your only issue is javascript injection style attacks...

Comment: @Chris: Also, it's impossible to validate the crypto code's authenticity (e.g. against MITM) - whose keys are you using for encryption? Are you using the right library, or one that's *subtly* broken? (for that matter, does a cryptographically sound implementation of the algorithm in JS even *exist*?)