# Ruby: XOR each char in a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xor

In C++, I can use the following code to implement the functions.

```
char result=0;
for(char c:s)
   result^=c;
```

However, when I try to implement this in Ruby, it fails.

```
result=0
s.chars.each do |c|
   result^=c
end
```

How should I XOR each char in a string in Ruby? Thanks very much!

Comment: I do not want to output hex number. Instead, I intend to output a ASCII character.

Comment: The code difference between printing the hex number and printing the ASCII character is very small.  For that reason, and because SO is not a code-writing service, I'll second the nominated exemplar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348991/xor-of-string-in-ruby use `.bytes` or `.each_byte` instead of `.chars`.